# I have a table and I want colored red

Tags: php, html, colors

What i have:

[image]

What i need:

[image]

I want code for color table red.

I try to search on internet and nothing good. i find only how to background the table.

Comment: A code example would be helpful, but it seems like what you're trying to ask for is the "border" attribute.

Comment: `border: 1px solid red;` :)

Comment: <input name="name" type="text" border: 1px solid red; required="" maxlength="8" value=""> i try this but dont work. sry im new in php/html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the border attribute of CSS.

You can set the border width, the border style (solid, dotted etc.) and the color.

Try this:

```css
table, tr, td{border: 1px red solid;}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    Test
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <input name="name" type="text" border: 1px solid red; required="" maxlength="8" value=""> what i need to do

Comment: You must set your style in the style attribute, try this:

   
 
<input name="name" type="text" style="border: 1px solid red; " required="" maxlength="8" value="">

Comment: you say.. i need set my style in css? how can i do this? sry im noob.. just can you make example for me?

Comment: The are diffrent ways to use CSS in HTML. 
In my previous comment I set the CSS in the style-attribute. 

An other way: Use the style tag in the head of your HTML document:
<style>
 input{border: 1px red solid;}
</style>

Or you can make a CSS file and include it with the link tag of HTML.